# How to generate token for authentication?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, postman

I need to generate a token to do the CRUD operations by fetching the API requests.
I have used the code snippet from the Postman. The token is getting generated in the Postman. But when I am generating in React. It is showing this :
[Error] https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahwUp.png

This is the code snippet that I copied from Postman :

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
myHeaders.append("Cookie", "esctx=AQABAAAAAAD--DLA3VO7QrddgJg7WevrQx7IG43UK7gipYHXtqZImLB1jfBLK4PTkZlgLq3BvpTizt3xt8EZQrpUJGa0hTnSdpRf-AenJvnGNABiv2cWYWSyJj9QNm-vWalRGHuDZ6Km_DaX_5CQHUa4H8U-osEGCM48buOyj0G819e1NoxuvoOD6fZvMI5nnDWZyjNa1mogAA; fpc=An1vbDtRI8BAiCLlUBBGpFXf9_srAQAAAA6uptkOAAAA; stsservicecookie=estsfd; x-ms-gateway-slice=estsfd");

var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");
formdata.append("client_id", "a01d4a9b-fda6-46e4-9174-661a6673acdc@834fb7b4-624d-4de8-a977-2d46ad979bd9");
formdata.append("client_secret", "oczmqK3VSCylwZtJba9fwTEpRYpKykge3AmZVCHLmUc=");
formdata.append("resource", "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/cooponline.sharepoint.com@834fb7b4-624d-4de8-a977-2d46ad979bd9");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: formdata,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/834fb7b4-624d-4de8-a977-2d46ad979bd9/tokens/OAuth/2", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Can someone please help me with the solution?

Comment: Your backend is not accepting request from host>  "http://localhost:3000"   find a way to enable it.

Comment: how to enable it? I am not able to understand anything. I am new to this. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to my question and would like to share the answer, so that it might help other users in future.

In order to get rid of `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header`, you need to add `"proxy": "https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/",` in the package.json file and remove the proxy from `fetch` in your JS file. Your fetch should look something like this : `fetch("834fb7b4-624d-4de8-a977-2d46ad979bd9/tokens/OAuth/2", requestOptions)`

> Note: This is a temporary solution as its for development purpose. In
> order to fix it permanently, you need to add the proxy in your server when you deploy it in the real world environment.

Thank you!
Happy Coding!